# Ant standalone package or another installer (for java web-app, windows)

Tags: java, windows, web-applications, ant, installation

I would like to create an installer for my app. Since I am using ant for build automation, I would like to use ant for installation purposes as well, but I want to save the user as much trouble as possible, including installing ant.

Is there a way to create a stand-alone ant bundle (one that would not depend on ant being installed in the system), or is there another way to create an installer? I have to install Apache Tomcat, MySQL and some other things on Windows.

Comment: You can zip entire ant and unzip some where in temp. You can invike ant as java program- well .. java should be present. 

Ant is not the tool we need here. To help install you need to tool that understand underlaying platform. For example querying registry, create services, stop and start service, handling user-access control etc. Commercial solutions are many, many open source solutions too.

Comment: Yes, understanding the platform is a good point, but it increases the complexity of the task a lot. So the idea for now is to create something simple, like a self-extracting zip that would just place the correct executables and configs to correct places. And then a bat file to start the whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [ANT installer package](http://antinstaller.sourceforge.net/).

Take care when writing custom installers for other people's applications (thankless task). For 3rd party dependencies that your application has, I would consider using tools like [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) and [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/). The only issue is that windows support from both these tools is only emerging at the moment.

Comment: Thanks! Had a brief look at it and it looks pretty much what I have been looking for.